# Boundedness question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

How do I prove this statement:

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence of positive numbers and $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \to L$ where $L > 1$, then $(x_n)$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We have that for any $0<\epsilon<L-1$ there is an $m$ such that for all $n\in\Bbb N$:
$$x_{n+m}\ge x_m\cdot (L-\epsilon)^n \,.$$

Comment: So I take ϵ = (L-1)/2. Then there exists a natural number K such that for n>K, x(n+1)/x(n) > L-ϵ = (L+1)/2. I'm stuck here.

Comment: Yes. My $m$ is your $K$, and my $n$ is your $n-K$. And you need the telescopic product:
$$\displaystyle\frac{x_{K+1}}{x_K}\cdot\frac{x_{K+2}}{x_{K+1}}\cdot \ldots \cdot\frac{x_{K+s}}{x_{K+s-1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contradiction. Suppose $x_n$ is bounded.  Then, for all $n,  x_n < M$ for some $M < \infty$.  But $$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \rightarrow L = 1 + \delta, \text{ say, for } \delta > 0.$$

So as you discuss with Berci, there is some $K$ for which, for all $n > K$, 
$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} >  1 + \frac{\delta}{2} > 1$$ and so for any $t > 0$

$$\frac{x_{K+t}}{x_K} >  (1 + \frac{\delta}{2})^t.$$

Given large enough $t$, $(1 + \frac{\delta}{2})^t$ can be as large as you like.  In particular, choose $t$ large enough such that

$$(1 + \frac{\delta}{2})^t > \frac{M}{x_K}.$$ Then

$$x_{K+t} > x_K * (1 + \frac{\delta}{2})^t > M$$

contradicting the assumption that $x_n$ is bounded.